# Can't post to the Facebook Wall: "Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can."

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Today, all of a sudden, we found out that we can't post to our company's page anymore. Whenever we try we get weird and completely non informative: `"Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can."`

[image]

Any ideas what could that be and how to get rid of it? We couldn't find any useful hint on the web. And Facebook doesn't reply to our support ticket,

Comment: Screenshot says that this is an error on the page `La Place`. Please confirm if you are facing this error on a facebook page?

Comment: I couldn't. Could you? Is listed there at all? How anyone is supposed to find anything on a page that doesn't have a search field?

Comment: As far as I could get it is not listed there.

Comment: (no disrespect meant) Your question should be directed to Facebook at https://facebook.com/help/bugs or https://facebook.com/help/suggestions.  [so] is **not** Facebook customer support...

Comment: I did file a bug on there about our issue, but there was no response so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue disappeared. Might be that Facebook received our bug ticket after all and silently fixed it. Or it was some kind of anomaly that went away with a scheduled cleanup. Who knows?

But I should say that this didn't save us or anyone from angry bosses, shouting clients and smart ITs... Everyone got a nice punch into the nose (I love you Facebook).

So for anyone having the same issue, simply file a ticket on Facebook and wait... there's nothing else you can do. Do not post your question here or anywhere, just wait, otherwise in addition to your nerves and concern, you will get some nice downvotes too... :D

Comment: This is an inevitability when working with 3rd party platforms.  You should ensure that your clients/bosses are aware of issues like these.  We had our applications and users disabled a little while ago for violating the platform policy and there is really nothing you can do other than send Facebook an appeal.  Luckily for you this was a transient issue :P